# Query for view variables inside directive not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have a directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})

export class MyDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper;
  @ViewChild('list') list;

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    // Both of these are undefined 
    console.log(wrapper, list);
  }
}
```

Which needs to query for variables in the view that is it being used in.

So say I have this template in one of my components, `MyComponent`:

```
<div #wrapper myDirective>
  <ul #list></ul>
</div>
```

It needs to find these variables, but the directive never manages to do this the way I have it now. My guess as to why this is happening is that since the directive doesn't actually have a view, `ngAfterViewInit` runs too soon and/or `@ViewChild` tries to find `wrapper` and `list` in the wrong place.

How can I make sure that the directive can find the variables?

Comment: Have you included it in the `declarations` for your module? What (if any) messages are you getting in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `ViewChild` to `ContentChild`. I suppose it should work

```
export class MyDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @ContentChild('wrapper') wrapper;
  @ContentChild('list') list;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.wrapper, this.list);
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/BTIg5ESoir46toMLFiLp?p=preview)**

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Me neither, but apparently they do.